# Creating a Multi-Contact Event with Apex in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am attempting to use Apex to create a multi-contact event.

I have already enabled `Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events` in the activity settings in the scratch org.

I am following the guide and the example at the bottom of [these](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) docs but I am constantly getting an error when pushing to the scratch org:

```
// ...
event.setEventWhoIds(attendeeContactIds);
// ...
```

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setEventWhoIds(List<String>) from the type Event`.

I also tried to write directly to the field with:

```
event.EventWhoIds = attendeeContactIds;
```

With that, I get the error, that the field is not writable.

`attendeeContactIds` is a List of Strings representing Contact IDs.

What could I be missing? ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bit stupid, it's readonly in apex. It's exposed so integrations can quickly create event and essentially a related list together in one all-or-nothing transaction. See also https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238094/eventwhoids-is-not-writeable-in-apex-class-but-working-on-jsforce

Try something like that?

```java
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

event e = new Event(
    StartDateTime = System.now(),
    EndDateTime = System.now().addHours(1)
);
insert e;

List<EventRelation> invitations = new List<EventRelation>();
for(Contact c : [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 5]){
    invitations.add(new EventRelation(
        EventId = e.Id,
        RelationId = c.Id,
        IsInvitee = true
    ));
}
insert invitations;

Database.rollback(sp); // unless you really want to send it out
```